# FOL translation, and definition of a "block" questions.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I'm trying to figure out the following translation from English sentence to FOL, and I have some questions:

**Let the binary predicate $LeftOf(x,y)$ be $x$ is left of $y$**

**Let the ternary predicate $Between(x,y,z)$ mean $x$ is in between $y$ and $z$** where $x,y,z$ are variables.

**Let the binary predicate $BackOf(x,y)$ mean $x$ is in the back of $y$**

**Question 1:**
"Every small *block* is between two others"

For this question, I would assume that a *block* involves all Tet, Cube, Dodec in the Blocks Language. And this sentences seems impossible since the last and first cube can't be between anything. So, the translation should be: $\forall x [((Cube(x) \vee Tet(x) \vee Dodec(x)) \wedge Small(x)) \rightarrow \exists y \exists z(Between(x,y,z) \wedge x \neq y \wedge x\neq z \wedge y \neq z \wedge ((Cube(y) \vee Tet(y) \vee Dodec(y))\wedge((Cube(z) \vee Tet(z) \vee Dodec(z)) \wedge Small(y) \wedge Small(z))]$ 
The reason I used inequality is to show that $x,y,z$ are not the same object. However, this doesn't look right, because the English sentence says that the small block must be between two other blocks with the same property, but the above FOL could be that a Tet is between a Cube and Dodec, or a Dodec is between two Tet's, which seems vague. I am not sure about this. Maybe if we only assume a block as a Cube, then:

$\forall x [(Cube(x) \wedge Small(x)) \rightarrow \exists y \exists z (Cube(y) \wedge Cube(z) \wedge Small(y) \wedge Small(z) \wedge Between(x,y,z) \wedge y \neq z \wedge x \neq y \wedge x \neq z)]$

**Question 2:** "Every cube in back of a dodecahedron is also smaller than it."

Translates to: $\forall x [Cube(x) \rightarrow \exists y(Dodec(y) \wedge BackOf(x,y) \wedge Smaller(x,y))] $

**Question 3:** "Every large cube is in back of some small tetrahedron." Translates to:

$\forall x[(Cube(x) \wedge Large(x)) \rightarrow \exists y(BackOf(x,y) \wedge Tet(y) \wedge Small(y))]$

**Question 4:** "No Dodecahedron is the same size as any tetrahedron." Translates to:

$\forall x \neg (Dodec(x) \rightarrow \forall y(Tet(y) \rightarrow SameSize(x,y)))$

**Question 5:** "If a tetrahedron has something to its left, then it is large." Translates to:

$\exists x(Tet(x) \wedge \exists y LeftOf(y,x)) \rightarrow \exists xSmall(x)$

I will appreciate it very much if anyone can verify my solutions and help me with my confusion on question #1.

Thank you.

Comment: sorry my bad, I forgot to add the definitions

Comment: For 1:  Yes, in the blocks world every block is a Cube, Tet, or Dodec, ... but since the domain is exactly that blocks world, you don;t actually have to specify any of those predicates at all: As soon as you quantify, you're talking about a block. So, you can simply say: $\forall x (Small(x) \rightarrow \exists y \exists z (x \not = y \land x \not = z \land y \not = z \land Between (x,y,z)))$

Comment: For 2: Your sentence says that every cube is in the back of some larger dodecahedron, but you need to say that *if* it is the back of some Dodec, then it is smaller than it. Try again

Comment: For 4: If you bring the negation outside the quantifier, you get $\neg \exists x (Dodec(x) \rightarrow ...)$.  OK, that combination with existential with conditional should always raise a red flag!  Because notice: as soon as there is something that is not a Dodec, then the antecedent of the conditional will be false, and hence the conditional true, and hence the whole sentence is true ... and yet you haven't said anything about Dodec's at all!  OK, so that's not good. So instead, start with: $\neg \exists x (Dodec(x) \land ...)$

Comment: For 5: The problem here is that the '*it* in 'it is large' must refer back to the Tet, i.e. you must use the same variable, but you use a new quantifier, and thus a new variable here.  Also, : when it says 'if a tetrahedron ....', do you think they mean *some* or do they mean *any one*, i.e. *all*?

Comment: I think I understand it now. For #4 it should be  ¬∃x(Dodec(x)∧∀y(Tet(y)→SameSize(x,y))) and for #5 it should be ∀x[(Tet(x) ∧ ∃yLeftOf(y,x)) → Large(x)]. I always thought that when a sentence uses "a something..." we use existential, but after reading your insights, I realized that's not the case.

Comment: And for #2, I thought at first ∀x[(Cube(x) ∧ ∃y(BackOf(x,y) ∧ Dodec(y))  → ∃ySmaller(x,y)] But as you've mentioned, a new quantifier should have new variable for Smaller(x,y), so this is wrong. So, I started with existential:  ∃y[∀x(Cube(x) → (BackOf(x,y) ∧ Dodec(x)) ∧ Smaller(x,y)] this may look a little weird, im not sure if it's correct though.

Comment: Hey; just noticed your updates ... make sure to 'ping' me by using @Bram28 in your comments.  Anyway ...4 ... is good ... 5 ... is also good ... 2 ... no.  OK, 2 (like 5, actually) is what is called 'donkey sentence', so-called after the rather violent classic example of "Any farmer who owns a donkey will beat it".  Now, clearly this is about all farmers, so a universal there, but what about the donkeys?  It *seems* like you need an existential, as it says 'a donkey', but if you think about it, you'll find that, like 5, it is about *all* donkeys. OK, so try that.

Comment: @Bram28 Thank you so much Bram!! I remember there is an example in my textbook regarding the donkey sentence. I'm gonna review that chapter again. Also, my assignment which includes the above questions was due 5hours ago, and thank you for saving my butt just before I had to hand it in lol! I fixed all of them but #2, but still I really appreciate your help and you taking the time to read all the my questions. Again, thank you so much for the help!